# Logic behind F-test for the coefficients test in linear regression

Tags: multiple-regression, f-test

In book I have the following sentence:
[image]

How can we understand "precisions" of different coeffcients(I am not native english speaker)?
And why do we use quadratic function, in order to solve this problem?

Comment: "Precision" often is used to mean the reciprocal of the variance.

Comment: Do not worry about your English, your question is perfectly clear.